# Is it possible to add emulate_tty option in a yaml launch file?

Tags: ros2

I know this option can be added when writing a launch file in python like this:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    node = Node(
        package='test_pkg',
        executable='"main',
        output='screen',
        emulate_tty=True,
    )
```

I'm wondering if the emulate_tty option can be added in yaml launch file as well